# JUnit 4 Test Execution in the order how they are programmed in class

Tags: java, testing, junit, automated-tests, rest-assured

I am using JUnit and RestAssured create API tests.

I was wondering if there is a way to execute test cases in the order how they are written in the class file. Currently when I execute them it seems random.

I tried `@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)` and adding `@Order(xy)` into the tests but I think that this didn't help me.

Just to describe my problem:

I have multiple tests in the following order in the class: Post tests, Get Tests, Delete tests.  As you may already know I want Delete tests to be executed as very last.

Is it possible to do it somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. IMO it is not even possible because your order of methods is not visible in the generated byte code, but I'm not a byte code expert and may be wrong.

The annotation `@TestMethodOrder` is part of JUnit Jupiter (JUnit 5) and therefore it does not work with JUnit 4 tests. JUnit 4 has an annotation [`@FixMethodOrder`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/FixMethodOrder.html) that allows you to execute test methods in alphabetic order. By prefixing your test names with some String like `a_` you can achieve what you want. I know it's ugly.